# Restarted Azure VPS maintaining the previous RDP connection

Tags: azure, vps

So I run a VPS with Microsoft Azure which is automated to shut down for the weekend (shuts down Friday night and starts up Sunday night. However, every time the VPS starts up, I have to establish a new RDP connection by going into my Azure portal and selecting "Connect" - which then overwrites the current RDP Connection on my desktop.

Is there a way in which I can maintain the same RDP connection whilst, at the same time, am able to shut down and start my VPS up again?

Comment: Do you have a static ip with your instance ?

Comment: any update in this case?

Comment: Sorry I haven’t replied, been flat out busy these past few days. I’ll look into your suggestions and let you know the outcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the assignment to static from virtual machine---networking---public IP address---configuration then save it.

[image]

If you set your Azure VM with a static Public IP, the IP address will not change even you shutdown or restart it. So you can maintain the same RDP connection. You can get more details about [IP address types and allocation methods in Azure.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#allocation-method)

Comment: @ToddGilbey  Glad to help you, nice day.